# Detect a certain key press

Tags: c++

My program currently displays text requesting which operation you would like to perform (1,2,3,4), I want the program to output a certain message depending on which key (1,2,3,4) is pressed.

```
{ 
    int option;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Choose an operation to perform." << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Calculate Determinants of Matrices [Enter 1]" << endl;
    cout << "Calculate Sum of Matrices [Enter 2]" << endl;
    cout << "Calculate Difference between Matrices [Enter 3]" << endl;
    cout << "Calculate Product of Matrices [Enter 4]" << endl;

    cin >> option;

    if (option == 1);
    {
        cout << "Determinant of A = " << endl;
        cout << "Determinant of B = " << endl;
    }

    if (option == 2);
    {

        cout << "Sum = " << endl;
    }

    if (option == 3);
    {
        cout << "Difference = " << endl;
    }

    if (option == 4);
    {
        cout << "Product = " << endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: It displays all of the statements regardless of which key is pressed.

Comment: I've fixed it, had to remove the ; and change the last 3 if's to else if. Thanks

Comment: @user3582798:that's what i answerd..!!

Comment: Suggestion:  use `swtich` statement, this looks like a perfect fit.

Comment: What do you mean? MCFC

Comment: @user3582798:see my answer below and if that is what helped you accept my answer..so that other's can know..!!

Comment: Please update your question with all the neccessary information you gave in the comments.

Comment: @Lillesort131 Awww! The edit apparently invalidated the question/answer. Don't do that!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove all unnecessary `;`s:

```
if (option == 1);
                ^
```

---

P.S.: as @ThomasMatthews commented, better to use `switch` here:

```
switch (option)
{
case 1:
    cout << "Determinant of A = " << endl;
    cout << "Determinant of B = " << endl;
    break;
case 2:
    ...
case 3:
    ...
case 4:
    ...
default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: unnecessary is too nice a word. They are just wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `switch` statement (I find `if-else-if` ladders unreadable).

```
switch (option)
{
    case 1:
        cout << "Determinant of A = " << endl;
        cout << "Determinant of B = " << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Sum = " << endl;
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "Difference = " << endl;
        break;

    case 4:
        cout << "Product = " << endl;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Unknown selection." << endl;
        break;
}
```

A more advanced technique is to use a look up table or a `std::map` and function pointers or function objects.

**Edit 1: Map of Function Objects**
The idea here is to look up a function to execute based on the number received from the User.

The tools we have are pointers to functions or *function objects* (functors), and `std::map`.

Let us define the Functor:

```
struct Operation
{
  virtual void operator() (void) = 0;  // Yes, a void parameter is my style.
};
```

We have define a base class with `operator()`.  This allows us to treat the class as a function call.  The `virtual`...`= 0;` says that this is an interface function and all descendants must implement it.

Next, we'll define a descendant class for summing.  The other options will have similar structure.

```
struct Sum_Operation : public Operation
{
  void operator() (void)
  {
    cout << "Accessing Summing operation.\n";
  }
};
```

Let's forward declare the other operations:

```
struct Determinant_Operation;
struct Difference_Operation;
struct Product_Operation;
```

Defining and initializing the map:

```
typedef std::map<unsigned int, Operation*> Operation_Container;

//...
Operation_Container menu1;
//...
menu1[1] = new Determinant_Operation;
menu1[2] = new Sum_Operation;
menu1[3] = new Difference_Operation;
menu1[4] = new Product_Operation;

// Executing the map function:
Operation_Container::iterator iter;
iter = menu1.find(option);
if (iter != menu1.end())
{
    // Execute the function
    (iter->second)();
}
```

I prefer arrays of  since the array can be updated or modified without change the look up functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try  **else if** and Remove all `;` used after condition statement

```
 if (option == 1)
    {
        cout << "Determinant of A = " << endl;
        cout << "Determinant of B = " << endl;
    }

   else if (option == 2)
    {

        cout << "Sum = " << endl;
    }

   else if (option == 3)
    {
        cout << "Difference = " << endl;
    }

  else  if (option == 4)
    {
        cout << "Product = " << endl;
    }
```

OR use **Switch case**

```
switch (option)
{
case 1:
        cout << "Determinant of A = " << endl;
        cout << "Determinant of B = " << endl;
        break;
case 2: cout << "Sum = " << endl;
        break;
case 3: cout << "Difference = " << endl;
        break;
case 4: cout << "Product = " << endl;
        break;
default:
        break;
}
```